# API Google [PHP] - Moments->insert and error 401

Tags: google-plus

I want to post a picture on Google+ with the API PHP. 
I have an error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message
    'Error calling POST [...] (401) Invalid Credentials'
```

This is my code. What's the problem? Thanks for your help.

```
require_once './src/Google_Client.php';
require_once './src/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('*****');
$client->setClientId('*******.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('*********');
$client->setRedirectUri('******/callback.php');
$client->setDeveloperKey('*********');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'));

$client->setUseObjects(true);


if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if (!$client->getAccessToken()) {

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";

} else {
$plus = new Google_PlusService($client);
$moment_body = new Google_Moment();
$moment_body->setType("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity");
$item_scope = new Google_ItemScope();
$item_scope->setId("target-id-1");
$item_scope->setType("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity");
$item_scope->setName("The Google+ Platform");
$item_scope->setDescription("A page that describes just how awesome Google+ is!");
$item_scope->setImage("./image.png");
$moment_body->setTarget($item_scope);   
$momentResult = $plus->moments->insert('me', 'vault', $moment_body);
}
```

https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to set the request_visible_actions parameters for the request:

```
$requestVisibleActions = array('http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity');
```